# sp_executesql returns nothing when parameter is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I've got this piece of code in my procedure:

```
   SET @Sql = 'SELECT @Value = ' + @Column + ' FROM #inserted'

   exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Value varchar(MAX) out', @NEW out


   SET @Sql = 'SELECT @Value = ' + @Column + ' FROM #deleted'

   exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Value varchar(MAX) out', @OLD out
```

And when the column value is null the variable `@OLD`doesn't have nothing and for some reason when I compare the 2 variables:

```
IF @NEW != @OLD
```

It doesn't get inside the `IF`, even if the `@OLD` is empty and `@NEW` isn't. I've tried this:

```
IF @OLD is null or datalength(@OLD)=0 or @NEW != @OLD
```

But still no good result. When I print the 2 variables the `@OLD` doesn't print anything (in the cases where is null in the table).

Can you help me?

Thank you :)

EDIT

This is a trigger that I built for some tables in my database when they're updated so I can save the changes made. To make it easy I created a loop trough the columns name of that table and for every column I do that piece of code that its giving me problems. Here's a bit more of my trigger:

```
WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MAX)
    BEGIN
       SELECT @Column = COLUMN_NAME, @Type = DATA_TYPE
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION = @LoopCounter and TABLE_NAME = 'Parameters'

       SET @Sql = 'SELECT @Value = ' + @Column + ' FROM #inserted'

       exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Value varchar(MAX) out', @NEW out


       SET @Sql = 'SELECT @Value = ' + @Column + ' FROM #deleted'

       exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Value varchar(MAX) out', @OLD out

       IF @OLD is null or datalength(@OLD)=0 or @NEW != @OLD
       BEGIN
         /* some code */
       END

       SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1 

END
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql like this inside a trigger?? This is a big red flag of things not going well inside your trigger. Perhaps reworking the trigger is a better approach. Can you post the entire trigger?

Comment: You have `triggers` tag in question, is this code executed from trigger?

Comment: @SeanLange see my update to the question.

Comment: @IvanStarostin yes it is executed when a table is updated.

Comment: To make it easier??? It made it more difficult for you since you are now posting a forum question to fix it. The other affect is it made is WAY slower. You really should consider a complete rewrite of this.

Comment: 1) this is horrible code for trigger 2) it won't work event with correct `if` in case when more than one row updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. Thank you for your tips. I changed my code to:

```
       SET @Sql = 'SELECT @Value = ' + @Column + ' FROM #inserted'

       exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Value varchar(MAX) out', @NEW out


       SET @Sql = 'SELECT @Value = ' + @Column + ' FROM #deleted'

       exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Value varchar(MAX) out', @OLD out

       IF ISNULL(@NEW,0) != ISNULL(@OLD,0)
```

With `ISNULL`everything goes ok. I've also had to use this in another place in my code where I was concatenating a `string`with the `@OLD`and `@NEW` values.

Thank you :)

Comment: for `varchar` variables?

Answer (score 0):

So check null states:

```
IF @NEW != @OLD
OR @NEW IS NULL AND @OLD IS NOT NULL
OR @OLD IS NULL AND @NEW IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
...
```

Comment: I've checked the null states but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think it is possible actually.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go proactive...don't execute if your @Column is null..

```
WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MAX)
    BEGIN
       SELECT @Column = COLUMN_NAME, @Type = DATA_TYPE
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION = @LoopCounter and TABLE_NAME = 'Parameters'

       IF ISNULL(@Column,'')<>''
           BEGIN
           SET @Sql = 'SELECT @Value = ' + @Column + ' FROM #inserted'

           exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Value varchar(MAX) out', @NEW out


           SET @Sql = 'SELECT @Value = ' + @Column + ' FROM #deleted'

           exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Value varchar(MAX) out', @OLD out

           IF @OLD is null or datalength(@OLD)=0 or @NEW != @OLD
           BEGIN
             /* some code */
           END
       END
       SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1 
END
```

Comment: The Column isn't `NULL` because it's the column name of the table. It's value it the one that can be null.

Comment: OK...but your question did state..."And when the column value is null the variable @OLD doesn't have nothing and for some reason when I compare the 2 variables:" . As Sean Lang mentioned, you should post entire trigger so we have an idea on what your trying to accomplish and could possibly provide options for you to try.